# click function stops hover function from working

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover, jquery-click-event

This is probably an easy solution but Im not getting it. So I have a one page site im working on a I have a jquery .click() function that changes the color of the navigation. I also have a .hover() function that also changes the color. The hover function works just fine until one of the navigation is clicked. Then the hover function stops working. here is my code

```
$(document).ready( function() {

$('nav a').click(function() {
$('nav a.lightGrey').css({color:'#888'});
$('nav a.darkGrey').css({color:'#555'});
$(this).css({color:'#0cf'});
});


$('nav a').hover(
function() {
$(this).addClass('hover')
},
function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hover')
}
);
});
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inline styles set by the [`css()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method  override styles from classes, unless you give `!important` to a style in a class.